# Error Thrown in console : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET - All browsers

Tags: iis

I was trying to open Angular 8 with the Net Core application, which was deployed on the IIS server. It throws the error message on the console "**Failed to load source: net:: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".** I found this bug in all browsers, not just Chrome. Can anyone help me solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error you can try to modify the connection_timeout attribute in iis which is how long a connection from a browser to the server should take till it times out.

Comment: The connection_timeout attribute is already given in IIS. This error came up in case I was trying to open three to four applications at the same time(ie, ). This error will not be thrown if I try to open the same application many more times.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on error message, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.